# python - xml to JSON - handling optional tags

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to convert an xml file to JSON.
In the python script, I am reading the xml file, store the tags in a dict and then dump into JSON.
The issue is that some of the tag in xml file are optional. As of now i am handling it via IF-conditions. I wanted to check is there is a better way of handling this?

My dict object looks something like this.
In this for example, some entries in the XML may have the tab for Variables, and others may not.

```
dictData[dictFolder['FOLDER_NAME']][dictJob['JOBNAME']] = {
          'Type' : dictJob['JOBTYPE'],
          'Command' : dictJob['SCRIPTNAME'],
          'Description' : dictJob['DESCRIPTION'],
          'When' : {'WeekDays' : dictJob['SCHEDULE'],
                    'FromTime' : dictJob['FROMTIME']},
                    'Variables' : [varDict],
                    'addInCondition' : {'Type': 'WaitForEvents',
                                        'Events' : jobINDict['Events']},
                                        'addOutCondition' : {'Type': 'AddEvents',
                                                             'Events' : jobOUTDict['Events']}                    
                                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

check out lxml2json (disclosure: I wrote it).

it can convert any xml element into its json equivalent, and gives a measure of control over the structure of the output:  including orderedDict, and which elements to render as list.

https://github.com/rparelius/lxml2json